# Sobrepor uma <button> a uma <img>

Tags: html, css

A ideia é fazer um "tumbnail" onde o botão play está (centrado) sobre a imagem...

```
<div>
<img src='imagems/imagem1.png'>
<button>Play</button>
</div>
```

Agradeço sugestões e a vossa disponibilidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minha solução consiste em um pouco de CSS3 e a adição de uma classe no HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail-wrapper">
    <img src="imagems/imagem1.png" />
    <button></button>
</div>
```

E o CSS:

```
.thumbnail-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.thumbnail-wrapper button {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform:translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```

Exemplo completo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/Xq68C/)**

Desta forma o botão vai ficar sempre centralizado no meio da imagem, independente do seu tamanho ou do tamanho da imagem abaixo dele.

Comment: A resolução do botão ao centro não podia estar melhor +1

Comment: Excelente solução, só o `box-shadow` no `hover` que não está funcionando no Firefox e IE :P, mais é questão de ajuste +1;

Comment: Seguindo a solução do Kazzkiq, tive a necessidade de adicionar uma outra <div></div> como apresento de seguida: <div class="thumbnail-wrapper"> <img src="imagems/imagem1.png" /> <button></button> </div> <div class="div-informacao-audio"> </div> A ideia é ter esta última <div> por baixo da anterior e encostada/alinhada à esquerda... No entanto, seguindo o css da primeira, as "tumbanails" aparecem no ecrã em forma de coluna. Já dei "voltas e voltas" na configuração do css e não consigo resolver o problema. O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 6):

Uma ideia sem mexer na tua *markup* é fazer uso de CSS para posicionar os elementos. Para o efeito usamos uma classe de CSS de forma a limitar o *scope* dos estilos aplicados:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/L6cxa/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-wrap">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/DXNAljCahPE/0.jpg">
    <button>Play</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-wrap{
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
.btn-wrap button{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:60px;               /* largura para o botão */
    height:30px;              /* altura para o botão */
    padding:0;
    margin:-15px 0 0 -30px;   /* margem à esquerda e ao topo metade da medida do botão */
    border:0 none;
}
```

**Resultado**

[image: Captura de Tela]

Answer (score 3):

Uma sugestão de implementação, não exatamente com `button`, mais também funcional:

**HTML**

```
<div class="video">
  <a href="#" title="Titulo do video">
      <img src="/img/local-da-imagem" alt="thumbnail"/>
      <span class="play"></span>    
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.video { 
    width: 250px; /*Tamanho da div com o thumbnail */
    height: 150px; 
}   
.video a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    display:block; 
}
.video a span.play {
    display:block;
    /*Imagem do play que irá aparecer inicialmente*/
    background: url('/img/local-da-imagem-do-play') center center no-repeat; 
    /*Definir valores conforme tamanho da imagem*/
    margin: -120px 10px 0 0; 
    height: 80px;
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 100; 
    opacity: 0.8; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); 
}
.video a:hover span.play {
    /*image que irá aparecer quando o mouse estiver em cima da imagem*/
    background:url('/img/local-da-imgem-quando-hover') center center no-repeat;
}
```

**Resultado**
[image: Resultado]
**Resultado hover**
[image: Resultado quando hover]

**Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfurlan/gTMmd/1/)**

Comment: Boa adaptação da _markup_ para uma forma mais _browser-friendly_ +1